# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error with dynamic sql for loop cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

This code compiles fine, but I get the below error when I run it:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "BOB.JUST_ME", line 69
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Possibly it's this line?

```
open cur for v_sql1 using TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;
```

In the dynamic SQL I've declared, I'm trying to select these values, but they don't get populated until the loop runs. Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it...

```
create or replace procedure JUST_ME is

--variables

l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
v_ts_name varchar2(30);
v_link_name varchar2(10);
v_csv_name varchar2(100);
EST_ONE_ROW_MB varchar2(100) ;
TOTAL_ROW_COUNT NUMBER;
SPACE_REQUIRED NUMBER;
TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB NUMBER;
v_Mv_name varchar2(100);
v_sql1 varchar2(1500);
cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
owner varchar2(100);
table_name varchar2(100);
driver_table varchar2(100);
mandatory_join varchar2(100);
C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT varchar2(100);
v_total_driver_only varchar2(100);
--

begin


SELECT tablename into v_csv_name
FROM BOB01.BOB_new_table_tracker
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from BOB01.BOB_new_table_tracker);

SELECT mv_name into v_Mv_name
FROM BOB01.BOB_new_table_tracker_mv
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from BOB01.BOB_new_table_tracker_mv);

select link_name into v_link_name from link_and_mail where mdate = (select max(mdate) from link_and_mail);
select distinct targetschema into v_ts_name from BOB01.MV_BOB_TABLE;

v_sql1 := 'SELECT /*+ monitor parallel (4)*/ a.owner,
                        a.table_name,
                        b.driver_table,
                        b.mandatory_join,
                        sum(c.sum_bytes) TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,
                        (TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB) / (:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) "EST_ONE_ROW_MB",
                        (EST_ONE_ROW_MB) * (:TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) SPACE_REQUIRED
                 FROM dba_tables@DB1 a, '|| v_Mv_name ||' b, MV_PRD_SEG_DATA c
                 WHERE a.table_name IN ( SELECT table_name
                                       FROM MV_BOB_TABLE
                                       WHERE driver_table IS NOT NULL
                                             AND   additional_joins IS NULL
                                     )
                 AND   a.owner IN ( SELECT DISTINCT productionschema FROM MV_BOB_TABLE c  )
                 and a.table_name = b.table_name
                 and a.table_name = c.segment_name
                 group by a.owner,a.table_name,b.driver_table,b.mandatory_join
               ORDER BY table_name';

file_handle := utl_file.fopen('ESTIMATES_CSV', v_csv_name||'_EST_PROC.csv', 'w', 32767);

--
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, 'The below report shows total row counts in PROD');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' for unjoined tables in the BOB document:');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,MANDATORY_JOIN,TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,EST_ONE_ROW_MB,TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,SPACE_REQUIRED');
--main loop
open cur for v_sql1 using TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;
   loop
      fetch cur into OWNER,TABLE_NAME,MANDATORY_JOIN,TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,EST_ONE_ROW_MB,TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,SPACE_REQUIRED;--,EST_ONE_ROW_MB;
      exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
      execute immediate' select /*+parallel (4)*/ count(*) from '||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

execute immediate' select /*+monitor parallel (10)*/ count(*) from ' ||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink||' b '||','||
driver_table || '@' || l_dblink||' a ' ||' where ' ||mandatory_join into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

execute immediate' select /*+monitor parallel (10)*/ count(*) from ' ||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink into C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                      OWNER || ',' ||
                      TABLE_NAME || ',' ||
                      TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB || ',' ||
                      TOTAL_ROW_COUNT || ',' ||
                      C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT || ',' || /* This is actually FULL_TABLE_COUNT*/
                      round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7)|| ',' ||
                      round(round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) * round(TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,0),0)
                      );


v_total_driver_only := v_total_driver_only + round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) * round(TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,0);

end loop;

UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                     'Total Estimated Space Required '|| round(v_total_driver_only,0) ||' MB'
                     );

utl_file.fclose(file_handle);

end JUST_ME;
```

I think it's possible that the code may have other issues, so if anyone sees a better way of doing it, please call it out! Thank you.

Comment: it's possibly the code in v$sql that's got the problem - you could try outputting that via `dbms_output.put_line` and then manually running the query to see if the problem lies there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here:

`(:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7)`

Specifically the `,7` is the cause of the error.